# Right click save link as then save

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

hello guys i want to right click save link as then save on the save pop up that windows shows.
this is an example:
https://www.who.int/data/gho/data/indicators/indicator-details/GHO/proportion-of-population-below-the-international-poverty-line-of-us$1-90-per-day-(-)

go on this page in the data tab u can see EXPORT DATA in CSV format:Right-click here & Save link
so if u right click and save link as it will let u save the data as csv.

i want to automate that can it be done using selenium python if so how?

i tried using actionchains but im not sure thats gona work

Comment: You can try getting the href attribute with: get_attribute("href") and execute driver get for the hyperlink

Comment: that gave me None because it seems like the <a> is in an iframe and selenium is not finding it nor beautifulsoup

Comment: What version of selenium do you use? It looks like the element is in some sort of shadow dom. You can check this article: https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/shadow-dom-in-selenium/

Comment: The report is inside an iframe and the EXPORT DATA link is inside an iframe inside the report!  So you need to switch through two levels of iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off using the Data API (json) offered on the same page, but I have managed to download the file using the code below and Google Chrome.

There is a lot going on which I didn't want to go into (hence the lazy usage of an occasional sleep), but the basic principle is that the Export link is inside a frame inside a frame (and there are many iframes on the page).  Once the correct iframe has been found and the link located, a right click brings up the system menu.

This menu cannot be accessed via Selenium (because it is inside an iframe?), so pyautogui is used to move down to "Save link as..." and also to click the "Save" button on the Save As dialog.:

```
url = "https://www.who.int/data/gho/data/indicators/indicator-details/GHO/proportion-of-population-below-the-international-poverty-line-of-us$1-90-per-day-(-)"
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 220);")
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#dataButton")
button.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_attribute((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#dataButton"), "class", "active"))
time.sleep(10)
iframes = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed'")
for i in iframes:
    try:
        driver.switch_to.frame(i)
        iframes2 = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='cvSandboxPack.html']")
        for i2 in iframes2:
            try:
                driver.switch_to.frame(i2)
                downloads = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[download='data.csv']")
                if len(downloads) > 0:
                    ActionChains(driver).context_click(downloads[0]).perform()
                    # Selenium cannot communicate with system dialogs
                    time.sleep(1)
                    pyautogui.typewrite(['down','down','down','down','enter'])
                    time.sleep(1)
                    pyautogui.press('enter')
                    time.sleep(2)
                    return
            except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
                continue 
            finally:        
                driver.switch_to.frame(i)  
                iframes2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))
    except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
        continue     
    finally:   
        driver.switch_to.default_content()  
        iframes = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed']")))
```

Comment: i switched to the correct iframe and i used driver.get(url) to open the download link url but the file is being downloaded in a location i dont want. i tried to use urllib to open the url like this: urllib.request.urlretrieve(csv_url, os.path.join(downloading_dir,'Data.csv')) downloading_dir is the directory i want the file to be downloaded and Data.csv the name. its giving me this error : URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: blob>